# calculate overlap of two parallel lines

Tags: php

I have 2 parallel lines in an 2D space.
The lines are defined with $min1, $max1, $min2, $max2

I already figured out how to check if they overlap:

```
function overlap($min1,$max1,$min2,$max2){
  if(($min1<$min2 && $max1>$min2) 
    || ($min1<$max2 && $max1>$max2) 
    || ($min1==$min2 && $max1==$max2) 
    || ($min2>=$min1 && $max2<=$max1)
    || ($min1>=$min2 && $max1<=$max2)){
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Now i have to check the overlaping length, but i have no idea how to implemnt this.

i need this to get the minmal translation vector in a separating axis theorem implementation

any hint would be great.

Comment: there's no such thing as "parallel" in 1D space...

Comment: @alnitak you could also argue there is no such thing as "not parallel" in 1D :P

Comment: How can it is possible to draw a line in 1D. All above are correct

Comment: @Alnitak, Nanne Thanks for blowing my mind this early on a Friday.

Comment: of course, i meant 2d. fixed it. sorry for that

Comment: But parallel lines NEVER overlap in 2D space (plane), unless they are on the same "line" in the plane, effectively making this a 1D question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just a quick thought, but I think it works.

Take the highest start value from the lines as `start'`
Take the lowest end value from the lines as `end'`

if `start' < end'` you have an overlap of (`end' - start'`)

Comment: thank you Nanne!  I did not expect that it is so easy. I already tried it with multiple conditions but this works perfekt.